# Is there a difference between slogans and brand statements?

Tags: marketing, business-writing, content-strategy

I once came across a set of brand guidelines and, in the *tone of voice* section, there was a list of *'brand statements'*. Multiple brand statements as examples of what the company could pick and choose to use throughout their marketing material.

Is the above method correct? If so then I can understand how brand statements would differ from slogans, as typically one brand would only have one slogan if I'm not mistaken.

But when I try to read up on the matter, the results I get look as though slogans and brand statements are the same thing.

If the two *are* the same thing, is there a name given for when a company might have a bunch of different headlines that they can use throughout their marketing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should expect to find a term like "brand statement" defined too rigorously. I think you will find different companies using different mechanisms to control their message and calling those mechanisms by different means.

I would take the meaning of "brand statement" to be a generic for things that the company wants to say about itself, independent of media and usage. The brand statements are the ideas about the company that the company wishes to convey to customers and potential customers through all the various media channels it uses. They are not necessarily finished sentences of paragraphs so much core ideas to be expressed.

A slogan (or a tagline) on the other hand is a specific piece of text used in a specific context in specific media. A slogan should conform to a brand statement. It is an instance and an instantiation of a brand statement.

I think you will find some mechanism similar to this in any company that takes its content strategy seriously, but I would not expect it to have one name or one precise mechanism across the board.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything about a brand statement, it is possible you are confusing the [Slogan vs Tagline](https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/slogan-vs-tagline-12643.html) debate. Here the two are easily confused as being one and the same when they are actually different.

A slogan is a short-lived marketing campaign representative of the current business model/product.  It is a short saying usually with wit and catchy to get stuck in people's heads. An example would be Verizon's "Can you hear me now?". They ran this slogan for several years before coming up with a new slogan to represent their business.

A tagline is more permanent. It represents your business and puts your company's values into another short saying. We can see these more prevalent in marketing when we see things like "Just do it" for Nike. These have been the tagline of the companies for many years while they have run other slogans to market new products.